# Syntax error for if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a conditional to an if statement in a rails helper.

```
<%= link_to "Admin", rails_admin_path, :class => "btn btn-success" if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_any_role? :superadmin, :admin %>
```

That returns a syntax error at that line:

```
SyntaxError at /
```

So how do I check to see if the user is signed in, and if they are, which role they have in 1 elegant line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Admin", rails_admin_path, :class => "btn btn-success" if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_any_role?(:superadmin, :admin) %>
```

Comment: Wow....I tried every other permutation with parens but not this. This works. Thanks! Will accept as soon as I can.